# LEDs on dimmer, left alone, eventually fade to off

Tags: electrical, wiring, led, dimmer-switch

I replaced some halogen bulbs in my recessed cans with some [LED retrofit kits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011ANB3RY)

I also replaced the dimmer with a new digital LED dimmer.  When I dim the lights down to a low-ish setting, I can wait about 45 mins and eventually the lights will be off.  I adjusted the minimum dimming range of the dimmer to something far higher than I want and the bulbs still eventually turn off.

I have the same dimmer in 2 other rooms with different LED bulbs and they work fine.  Though, the wiring might be a bit different.  The new one doesn't have a ground wire, but from what I've been told, that should matter because the old dimmer didn't have a ground either.

The new lights are also quite loud when fully bright.  They have an audible hum that none of my other lights have.  Do you think this is a problem with the lights or the dimmer?

I imagine that the hum means the transformer is not converting light efficiently,  could that be causing it?

Comment: I tried the link no luck. Some LED lamps have fans in the lamp base to cool the electronics, could this be the noise you are hearing? 45 minutes to go out? most dimmers I have installed the max time is 30 seconds. with the lamps taking so long to turn off and if they are dimming type of led (not all are), you may want to exchange the dimmer. A few years ago some of the dimmers had enough leakage current that the lights had a faint glow, but I haven't seen this in quite a while.

Comment: Im not actually trying to turn off the lights, I just want them on a low setting.  After sitting at that low setting, they very slowly start to fade, until they turn off.  Last night 3 of the 4 turned off and the fourth one immediately got brighter when the other 3 turned off. Also I updated the link, sorry typo

Comment: Missed that on the time line. There are different sizes of dimmers. Some are rated at 3 amps some 5 & some ~7 amps. If you have a larger one there may not be enough of a load for the dimmer to work properly. You may have better luck with one that is rated closer to the draw your lights need. Your 3 lights may only be drawing 45 watts or less than .4 amps with a 7/12 amp digital dimmer that may not be enough of a load. where a 3 amp model might dim further down and work better. hope that helps.

Comment: I believe this is the dimmer I have, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008X3CHM0/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awd_h0sbxb630YCFW I have 2 more of these driving GE LED bulbs in other rooms.  I can't imagine the amperage would be that different between the bulbs and the retrofit kits, but certainly worth looking into

Comment: Matthew this is the small model. I use the same one and have had great luck. Since the lamps are listed as dimmable, my only other guess is it could be a bad unit. I have not had a bad unit in quite a few years but it is possible.

Comment: I contacted the manufacturer of the bulbs and they suggested going with a specialized ELV or MLV dimmer depending on what the cans' transformers use. They are a low voltage system, so it makes sense.  Will try it out and report back

Comment: A replaced the bulbs with Sylvania bulbs and no longer have the problem.  The new bulbs don't dim nearly as well but they're silent and stay on